# ImageMagick Draw Text Not Working In Mountain Lion

Tags: imagemagick, osx-mountain-lion, imagemagick-convert

Just upgraded ImageMagick to 6.8.0-19 on my Mac and the drawing of text has suddenly stopped working. The current code is:

```
system("convert #{output.path} -fill black -pointsize 26 -gravity SouthWest -draw \"text 30,8 #{string}\" #{output.path}")
```

When I push my code to Heroku (running ImageMagick 6.5.7-8), the text still gets rendered fine. Anyone knows what's wrong?